# Как установить websocket-server?

Tags: linux, node.js, разработка-игр, npm

Решил сделать свою онлайн-игру. Но решил взять готовую, а потом переписывать. Взял BrowserQuest. Установил все модули NodeJs. Остался один: websocket-server.
Хочу установить, пишет ошибку 404.
Недавно переустановил npm, установив новую версию. Старый слетел.

```
Stas-PC quest # npm install websocket-server
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "websocket-server"
npm ERR! node v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.7
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-server
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'websocket-server' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/stasgames/quest/npm-debug.log
Stas-PC quest #
```

Как его поставить?
P. S. Ещё хотел спросить, как восстановить звук в Linux Mint, но не знаю, на StackOverflow ли это спрашивать.

Answer (score 2):

3 раз правлю коммент, пишите правильно! Не поймешь что у вас, толи java то ли javascript...

так же вот пример установки BrowserQuest https://stackoverflow.com/a/10357807
еще рекомендую http://socket.io/, если будете сами писать, а не переписывать BrowserQuest.

И судя по ошибке, такого пакета больше нет, или он "поврежден".
Неплохой совет:
Note that you can also install from a tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: Установилось. Но после того, как я ввожу имя, игра грузится бесконечно.

Answer (score 1):

рекомендую http://java-websocket.org/, простой, хороший, под томкат

Comment: Нужен именно websocket-server.
websocketserver не сработал. Переименовал каталог, какая-то библиотека отсутствует.

Comment: @Stasicheck а я что дал? там есть пример для установки сервера. у меня отлично работает

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй `npm install websocketserver`

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install node-websocket-server
```

Там с похожим названием есть [ещё несколько](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=websocket-server) – выбирайте.